# Twitter Bootstrap Ajax call error in dialog2.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

We are using Twitter Bootstrap for my application. I have situation where I have to pull the data from server and show it to popup/model div. We are using dialog2.js for it but it does work. We not want to use .load functionality as we are not using any single url call. We want it to do with “URL” by ajax call and response send back to popup/model content area. We have tried following

```
$('#proposalInDialog2').click(function(event){
var url="abc.do"
$('<div/>').dialog2({title: "Goals-Based Proposal", content: url});
});
```

Please help us to to find out this, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data from the same or a remote domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is simple, just set this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

And [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) cross domain requests will work

Comment: Thanks Florent and and W. Kristianto for editing, you guys are very help to new people :)